# php file not connect to database in cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I try to get data from my site's form & stored in sql but its shows database connection error.

Here's My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $contact = $_POST['contact'];

  $comment = $_POST['comment'];

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "epiz_22277887", "A6R6qtbEVDIe", "epiz_22277887_data") or die("ERROR: Could not connect database. ");
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (name, email, contact, comment) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$contact', '$comment')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("ERROR: Could not connect. ");
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
    <h1>Thank You for Contacting Us <?php echo "<span style='color:purple;'>$name</span>"   ?></h1>

        <h3>We will be contacting you soon</h3>     <a href="index.html">Click here for redirecting site..</a

            <?php
    }else{
?>  <p>Your account have been not registered yet.</p>
            <a href="index.html">Click here for redirecting site..</a>
    <?php }?>
</body>
</html>
```

The error is:
ERROR: Could not connect database.

Anyone tell me where I did mistake?

Comment: Are you sure data are stored in your db? may be those are previous ones.

Comment: Username, Password or Database name may be incorrect in your code.

Comment: instead of immediately ending the script, instead make use of `mysqli_error()` in your code to find the actual error message, and then output or log it somewhere so you can see it. That might give you a better clue. This is basic debugging which you should know how to do if you want to work with SQL. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php . After that you can kill the script if you want, or implement a more graceful error-handling solution.

Comment: Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are setting bad connection properties? By the way be careful with input variables located in your query. There is possible SQL injection - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection